# Will ssh tunnelling be a simpler way to solve my link encryption issue rather than stunnel?

Tags: ssh-tunnel, stunnel

We have an encryption issue from a vendors mid-tier to an [Oracle database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database). We can use [encrypted database connections](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf) and have done for 90% of cases.

Our security team has advised us that since this connection goes over a link, everything needs to be secure.

One database client is a proprietary vendor mid-tier for whom we have asked to upgrade with encrypted SSL JDBC links, and they have advised us the timeline for this is two years. We need to have a security solution in a shorter timeframe.

Our security team advised us that [stunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stunnel) might be a potential solution to this problem. This requires setting up a server, keys on the server and a client.

We already run an [ssh server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_servers) on the box that the Oracle database is running on, with keys for users setup.

It seems to me that stunnel duplicates the pattern of ssh.

1. server - [stunnel server](https://www.stunnel.org/howto.html) vs ssh server
2. server key setup - [stunnel key setup](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-ssl-tunnel-using-stunnel-on-ubuntu) vs openssh users [setting their keys on the server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2)
3. client - Using an [ssh client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_clients) vs [using a stunnel client](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-ssl-tunnel-using-stunnel-on-ubuntu)

Stunnel might be useful in cases where you're not already running an openssh server, or where you want a different key management system.

Now I might be missing something in my analysis. There might be a feature of stunnel that I need that I can't see.

My question is: **Will ssh tunnelling be a simpler way to solve my link encryption issue rather than stunnel?**

---

EDIT

- This link is already inside a secure network. It is not public. But it is financial services - where the threat model involves hard shell, soft core analysis. It's not good enough to have an insecure link inside a secure network - because you don't trust the inside of your network.

Comment: Is your Oracle database a RAC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just create an IPSec connection between the two systems and not worry about ssh/stunnel.

---

Today I would use [WireGuard](https://www.wireguard.com/). It's much simpler to set up and work with.

Comment: Thanks - that's helpful - I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: IPSec is probably still the answer.

Comment: Thanks - could you provide reasons as to why this is better?

Comment: IPSec is designed to be a host to host tunnel.

Comment: Thanks - what are the benefits over stunnel or ssh ?

Comment: stunnel is ssh tunneling.  It just doesn't spawn a shell.

Comment: From the WireGuard website you linked to: “WireGuard is not yet complete. _You should not rely on this code._”

Comment: I'm very aware of what the site says. This Q&A will be around long after that statement has been removed.

Comment: @Iain But you specifically say you would use WireGuard _today_. Change “today” to “when it’s complete and certified” and I’ll withdraw my objection.

Comment: No, I said 'consider using...'